# Media Query doesn't work correctly

Tags: css, debugging, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport

I'm trying to set a rule using media queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px){
    #dados_contato_rodape p{
        font-size: 5.5em;
        border: 1px solid yellow;
    }
}
```

But this format only applies when the screen width is 1930px or more (testing in addons responsive tools for Chrome).

My viewport tag is:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, maximum-scale = 1, minimum-scale=1" />
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dados_contato_rodape">
   <p>contato@contato.com.br</p>
   <p>55 51 9999 9999</p>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

If I put jQuery/Javascript code in this width screen (1920px), the result is 1920px:

```
$(window).outerWidth()
```

Media queries are working fine in other situations, but only in this case (until this moment) it's not working.

Can someone help me with it?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this on a Mac? (I'm wondering if the Mac's hidden scrollbar area is involved here.)

Comment: @ralph.m it's Windows... already... don't tell me that on a Mac I'll find other issues... :/

Answer (score 0):

Use a comparison of the jQuery method to the [CSSOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/) and documentElement properties:

```
var window_diff = window.outerWidth - $(window).outerWidth();
var screen_diff = screen.availWidth - $(window).outerWidth();
var document_diff = document.documentElement.clientWidth - $(window).outerWidth();
```

It looks like jQuery is using the `clientWidth` property.

Use `min-device-width` as an alternative:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1920px) { 
... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS screen widths and JS screen widths (both inner width and outer width) don't always match for all browsers.

This is the best explanation I know of: http://www.matanich.com/2013/01/07/viewport-size/

So in summary, trust your CSS @media setting rather over what's returned by JS in most situations.

Good luck!